# In front of the air conditioner's blown air

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

Could you possibly let me know whether the bold part below sounds idiomatic to you? If not, I would appreciate if you could tell me how would a native speaker phrase it in a natural way?

> - That was very hot out there! I had a quite hard working day and just got home. I felt a little drowsy. I lay on the couch and stretched myself out **in front of the air conditioner's blown air** and say: [Phewwwww!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "In front of the air conditioner" conveys the meaning. If you want something more dramatic, you could say "in front of the arctic blast from the air conditioner."

Answer (score 1):

> Air conditioner’s blown air

is not idiomatic in U.S. English (I shall not hazard a guess on whether it is idiomatic in other variants of English).

Language takes account of everyday experience. Sitting in front of an air conditioner has negligible effect if the air conditioner is not operating. If it is operating, it does so by blowing chilled air into the room. If it is operating and a person is sitting in the stream of air being emitted, they may feel relief from the temperature outside or uncomfortably chilled. Any person with the intelligence of a kitten knows that whatever is felt from an air conditioner is a result of its being operated and therefore blowing cold air. It avoids redundancy to say

> I eventually got chilled lying in front of the air conditioner

It sounds stiltedly absurd to say

> I eventually got chilled by lying in front of the air blown into the room from the fan in the operating air conditioner.

Now if you want to say something far less obvious, for example if the air conditioning was set to a very low temperature and the fan was set at maximum force, conditions that are not always true, then it might make sense to say

> I was quickly shivering from the arctic chill blasting from the air conditioner.